# PHP: How to use ereg to validate input text AND string length simultaneously?

Tags: php, posix-ere

I'm using ereg in the followin way to validate a field which can contain only numbers from 0 to 9:

```
if(eregi("^([0-9])*$", $mynumber)) return true;
```

However the string must have between 8 and 10 characeters. Is it possible to improve the same ereg usage to check for a valid string length as well?

Thanks in advance.. all ereg tutorials seem to be traditional chinese to me.  :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ereg*()` functions are deprecated, and will be removed in a future version:

```
if(preg_match("/^([0-9]){8,10}$/", $mynumber)) return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the `*` quantifier with `{8,10}`:

```
eregi("^[0-9]{8,10}$", $mynumber)
```

Now the regular expression only matches if the string consists of 8 to 10 digits.

And, by the way: The `i` in `eregi` is for case-insensitivity. But digits have no case. So you could use `ereg` instead. But since the use of [PHP’s POSIX ERE functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.regex.php) is deprecated in favor to [PHP’s PCRE functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php), you should use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) instead:

```
preg_match("/^[0-9]{8,10}$/", $mynumber)
```